# How to resolve UnsupportedOperationException?

Tags: java, unsupportedoperation

I'm trying to develop a simple SNMP GET/SET program in java using SNMP4j. I've followed the following tutorials

http://www.developer-tricks.com/2012/11/how-to-get-started-with-snmp4j.html

https://blog.jayway.com/2010/05/21/introduction-to-snmp4j/

I have also read through the 'Getting started with SNMP4J' stackoverflow thread.

Every tutorial and program I've tried to replicate so far to get me started has resulted in "**Error:java: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException**" when I compile. I can't figure out why. I used the exact code in both the tutorials I listed above, and both resulted in the same error as soon as I compile. I've read up on other threads involving the exception, but haven't found anything relevant to SNMP4j, a lot of what I read involved something with lists using the AsList method, which isn't used at all.

The code im trying to run is directly copied from the 'developer-tricks' link I posted earlier. The only difference is I changed the OID and IP address to ones for my own machine.

If anyone else has some experience in how to solve this exception, I would realy appreciate any advice.

**Here is the console output when I try to compile.**

> Information:javac 10 was used to compile java sources
>   Information:3/29/2018 4:19 PM - Compilation completed with 1 error and
>   0 warnings in 716ms Error:java:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Here is my code, nearly identical to the 'how-to-get-started-with-snmp4j' tutorial i linked to.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            Snmp snmp4j = new Snmp(new DefaultUdpTransportMapping());
            snmp4j.listen();
            Address add = new UdpAddress("192.168.1.10" + "/" + "161");
            CommunityTarget target = new CommunityTarget();
            target.setAddress(add);
            target.setTimeout(500);

            target.setRetries(3);

            target.setCommunity(new OctetString("public"));
            target.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version2c);

            PDU request = new PDU();
            request.setType(PDU.GET);
            OID oid = new OID(".1.3.6.1.4.1.34832.512.1.1.1.2");
            request.add(new VariableBinding(oid));

            PDU responsePDU = null;
            ResponseEvent responseEvent;
            responseEvent = snmp4j.send(request, target);

            if (responseEvent != null) {
                responsePDU = responseEvent.getResponse();
                if (responsePDU != null) {

                    Vector tmpv = responsePDU.getVariableBindings();
                    if (tmpv != null) {
                        for (int k = 0; k < tmpv.size(); k++) {
                            VariableBinding vb = (VariableBinding) tmpv.get(k);
                            String output = null;
                            if (vb.isException()) {

                                String errorstring = vb.getVariable().getSyntaxString();
                                System.out.println("Error:" + errorstring);
                            } else {
                                String sOid = vb.getOid().toString();
                                Variable var = vb.getVariable();
                                OctetString oct = new OctetString((OctetString) var);
                                String sVar = oct.toString();

                                System.out.println("success:" + sVar);
                            }


                        }

                    }

                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Can you please provide your code and the exact/complete error message. The more information you provide the easier it becomes to offer assistance.

Comment: @Mozahler I just edited my post with a little more info. Thanks

Comment: That's definitely better. Now you'll have to wait until some java programmers see your question. 

Comment: Is that the complete error message? Not even a line number? Right now I'm not sure where the `UnsupportedOperationException` comes from. If it's from `javac` itself, it could be that your installation of Java 10 is messed up.

Comment: @SeverityOne Yeah no line number or anything, thats why It seems so weird to me. UPDATE: Just tried running a 'Hello World', and still got the error. Seems like this has nothing to do with snmp4j. Once I figure out how to solve this, I'll return with an answer

Comment: Uninstall Java 10 and try JDK 8 or 9 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the error had nothing to do with SNMP4j. It happened with any program I compiled.

In order to fix this, I uninstalled JDK 10 and installed JDK 9 instead. I was using Intellij. Not sure exactly what caused this, but uninstalling and reinstalling was the solution.